# GIT permission denied (publickey) - Fatal could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I have `ssh -T git@github.com` command returning successfully authenticated.
I also have `ssh-add -l -E sha256` returning output.

But `git push -u origin main` returns

```
***@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the repository?

Comment: @ewong it is a private repository git remote add origin https://github.com/saumyaphilip/mgc_web.git

Comment: Either you used the wrong pubkey or there is something wrong with your repo (permission wise)

Comment: Why did you obscure the part before `@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`? That is, why the three stars there? You're required to use `git` here, so it has to read `git@github.com` to work, so there's no point in hiding the `git` part.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding as a remote an HTTPS URL (https://github.com/saumyaphilip/mgc_web.git)

That means your SSH key is not used at all.

Try at least to switch to SSH:

```bash
cd /path/to/repository
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:saumyaphilip/mgc_web.git
                          ^^^
```

As noted, the SSH remote user is always `git`.